# A word which means to "achieve love"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to form a sentence about the American Dream, but cannot find a particular word.

The American Dream is belief that hard work and ... can achieve prosperity and [...]

Prosperity/wealth means to have a lot or be content with money.

What would be the parallel to this for love? A word which describes one's content with the amount of love he or she has. (Being in love with you who want, satisfied with your love life, etc.)

Comment: *find* prosperity and love, not *achieve* them

Comment: You could consider altering the beginning of the sentence so that it's more like "The American Dream is the belief that one's efforts can result in an abundance of wealth and love."

Answer (score 2):

> **Gratification**
> [grat-uh-fi-key-shuh n]/
> noun
>
> 1. the state of being gratified; great satisfaction.

Or

> **Fulfilment**
> [foo l-fil-muh nt]/
> noun
>
> 1. the act or state of fulfilling: to witness the fulfillment of a dream; to achieve fulfillment of one's hopes.
> 2. the state or quality of being fulfilled; completion; realization:

Answer (score -1):

To have found "one's true love" or "one's soul mate" pretty much covers it. I don't think there is a *one word* answer that encompasses what you are looking for, at least in the English language.